# How to make all sounds have the same volume regardless of distance from sound source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ship explodes meteorites when laser collides them, sound creates in a meteorite position, sound in the center is the loudest, sound on the top is quiet, all audio sources are 2d in spatial blend.
[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LaserCollisions : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private ParticleSystem _explosion;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip _explosionAudio;
[SerializeField] private float _explosionAudioVolume;

public UIdata score;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Border"))
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

    if (other.CompareTag("Meteorite"))
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(_explosionAudio, transform.position, _explosionAudioVolume);
        Instantiate(_explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        score.Increment();
    }
}
}
```

All my audio sources have such characteristics
[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sounds have different volume, i want to make all of them same volume

Comment: Do you have `Spacial Blend` set to 3D on your AudioSource? Also check the `Volume Rolloff` curve and max distance settings

Comment: Spacial Blend set to 2D, if its 2D should i check Volume Roloff? Because its in 3D sound settings

Comment: Watch this tutorial about audio for 2D games: https://youtu.be/7e6GJtm3FU4?t=147 
  The video should start playing at 2:27 where `Spatial Blend` is mentioned. This almost definitely the cause of your issue, the only way the volume distance would be different was if it was set to 3D and not 2D... Make sure you are changing the root prefab of the meteorite when making changes to the audio source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your problem is the fact you're trying to play/spawn the audio at a specific position. This means Unity will treat the audio like real life, volume gets quieter the further you are from something.

Currently, the volume will depend on the position of the Audio Listener and the position of the Audio Source. Instead of AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint, you can use the AudioSource.Play method to play the sound globally. This method plays the audio clip attached to the AudioSource component of the game object it is called on.

Change your code to call the Play method on the AudioSource component like so:

```
private void Start()
{
    // Get the AudioSource component
    _audioSource = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Border"))
        Destroy(this.gameObject);

    if (other.CompareTag("Meteorite"))
    {
        // Set audio clip
        _audioSource.clip = _explosionAudio;
        // Play sound
        _audioSource.Play();

        // Continue with your code...
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I thought Play() would just play at its current position. I would go into the audiosource and increase the minimum distance a bunch so it can be heard everywhere. The audiosources could also be moved to the same object as the audiolistener.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right about the Play method. It has to be the Spatial Blend, it mustn't be set to 2D?‍♀️

Comment: I used PlayClipAtPoint because .play() doesn't begin clip, because i delete current object after playing clip, i tryed .play() now and there wasn't any sound

Comment: Yeah, it this isn't the solution unfortunately. Check out my comment on your answer, I'm pretty certain that the problem is to do with the `Spatial Audio`

Comment: Spatial Audio in my project set to 2D as you advised

Comment: Then I really do think it has to be to do with the `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint`... looking at the docs, the position parameter is: "Position in world space from which sound originates" and I reckon it must automatically set the sound to 3D for this reason. Try creating a separate Audio Source on a Game Object that just sits somewhere in the scene. In the script you provided, find this audio source in code and use it to `AudioSource.Play()` the sound.

Comment: ooooor, just use this sound manager like I'm sure everyone does lol... https://youtu.be/6OT43pvUyfY

Comment: Worked with using separate Audio Source, thanks